# fullcalendar '+ more' link not displaying all events for the day as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have 4 events on one day.

When I set eventLimit to 3 it displays '+2 more' as expected.

But when you click on '+2 more' it only displays the 2 events that are already visible when it should display all events for that day.

When I set eventLimit to 4 all 4 events display fine.

**How can I get all 4 events to display when you click '+2 more'????**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.css' />
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.js'></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="calendar">
    </div>

<script>
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
  {editable: false,
   firstday: 1,
   eventLimit: 3,
   eventTextColor: 'white',
  events:[ 
    {
      title: 'Multi day event 1',
      start: '2014-11-09',
      end:   '2014-11-16'
    },
    {
      title: '1 Day event 1',
      start: '2014-11-12',
      end:   '2014-11-12'
    },
    {
      title: '1 Day Event 2',
      start: '2014-11-12',
      end:   '2014-11-12'
    },
    {
      title: '2 Day event',
      start: '2014-11-12',
      end:   '2014-11-14'
    } 

]}
);
  </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'have the same problem. Let me know if you get an answer. I still havent got any replies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an issue with your `events` array, specifically with those that don't appear on the popover (*1 Day event 1* and *1 Day Event 2*).

By the description you have, I'm assuming these will be all day events. If this is the case, you should define the events in the following manner (remove the `end` option and add `allDay: true`):

```
{
    title: '1 Day event 1',
    allDay: true,
    start: '2014-11-12'
}, 
{
    title: '1 Day Event 2',
    allDay: true,
    start: '2014-11-12'
},
```

If the events aren't supposed to be all day, then you must define the time part, as such:

```
{
    title: '1 Day event 1',
    start: '2014-11-12T12:00:00',
    end:   '2014-11-12T16:00:00'
},
{
    title: '1 Day Event 2',
    start: '2014-11-12T18:00:00',
    end:   '2014-11-12T20:00:00'
},
```

Check [**this jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/k93rq1qy/), where I've changed those events with the options I'm presenting here.